# Pulling Android Clipboard Data into Java Application

Tags: java, android, clipboard, appium, clipboardmanager

I have a java application intended for a specific purpose. As part of the application, I want to pull the clipboard data from the attached Android Device. Is there any way to retrieve data residing in the Android Device's clipboard into the Java Application? I do not have any android app running on the device.

Is there any way to achieve the same via Appium?

Answer (score 0):

You can Access Android clipboard content.for sharing the content to your java application you need a connection between android and your java app.i think you can do it with a TCP socket connection.

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
```

for  setting text to clipboard you can use this.

```
clipboard.setText("Text to copy");
```

for getting data from clipboard use this.

```
clipboard.getText();
```

after getting your data from clipboard send it to your java application via Socket

Comment: I do not have any android application running on the device. Should I have to use ClipboardManager inside my Java application. Is it compatible? What if the device is not directly connected to host where java application is running?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could make your android app listen for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` broadcast. This broadcast's intent contains whether you are connected through plug or USB. You can find the sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7156252/2367703).

Once you know you are connected through USB, you could access the ClipBoardManager like [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_clipboard.htm), and copy it's contents to a file.

Then finally you could just pull the file using adb, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795186/transfer-files-from-android-to-computer-via-usb-programmatically).

**Suggestion:**

If you know that your mobile and desktop application are on the same network, you could just `POST` your clipboard data to a server running on your desktop app, or make a Socket Connection.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, I do not have any control on the android app that is running on the device. And ClipBoardManager cannot be used from a Java application directly.